# Phaser Bitmap to Image

Tags: bitmap, phaser-framework

Is it possible to create an image out of a bitmap in Phaser?

What I was trying to do is to transform/re-shape a sprite to trapezoid.

1. Load sprite atlas
2. Add sprite to canvas
3. Redraw the sprite to a bitmap data
4. Redraw the bitmap data to transform into trapezoid
   using the function below:

   ```
   /**
    * Created by Ken Fyrstenberg / Epistemex
    * License: CC3.0-Attr.
    * 
    */

   function drawTrapezoid(ctx, img, x, y, w, h, factor) {
       var startPoint = x + w * 0.5 * (factor * 0.01),
               xi, yi, scale = img.height / h,
               startLine = y,
               endLine = y + h;

       for(; y < endLine; y++) {

           xi = interpolate(startPoint, y, x, endLine, (y - startLine) / h);
           yi = (y * scale + 0.5) | 0;

           ctx.drawImage(img, 0, yi, img.width, 1, xi, y, w - xi * 2, 1);
       }

       function interpolate(x1, y1, x2, y2, t) {
           return x1 + (x2 - x1) * t;
       }
   }
   ```

The problem is this, function uses image to redraw. I only have bitmap data.
Is it possible to create image from bitmapdata like `bitmapdata.generateImage();` sort of?

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = game.add.image(0, 0, bitmapdata); // x, y, key for the image
```

Simple as that. Same goes if you want a sprite instead of an image: `game.add.sprite(0, 0, bitmapdata)`.